# reactstrap styles not being loaded in react 16.8

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

Tools:

React 16.8.3
reactstrap 7.1.0

I followed the instructions here `https://reactstrap.github.io/` but I'm still getting errors. I'm aware of this solution from their github page:

```
{ test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' }
```

but that config file seems to be outdated. I'm only getting this error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'style-loader!css-loader'
```

Here's my webpack config:

```
const getStyleLoaders = (cssOptions, preProcessor) => {
const loaders = [
  isEnvDevelopment && require.resolve('style-loader'),
  isEnvProduction && {
    loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
    options: Object.assign(
      {},
      shouldUseRelativeAssetPaths ? { publicPath: '../../' } : undefined
    ),
  },
  {
    loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',
    options: cssOptions,
  },
  {
    // Options for PostCSS as we reference these options twice
    // Adds vendor prefixing based on your specified browser support in
    // package.json
    loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
    options: {
      // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
      // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2677
      ident: 'postcss',
      plugins: () => [
        require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
        require('postcss-preset-env')({
          autoprefixer: {
            flexbox: 'no-2009',
          },
          stage: 3,
        }),
      ],
      sourceMap: isEnvProduction ? shouldUseSourceMap : isEnvDevelopment,
    },
  },
].filter(Boolean);

{
   test: cssRegex,
   exclude: cssModuleRegex,
   use: getStyleLoaders({
            importLoaders: 1,
            modules: true,
            localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
            sourceMap: isEnvProduction
              ? shouldUseSourceMap
              : isEnvDevelopment,
          }),
          // Don't consider CSS imports dead code even if the
          // containing package claims to have no side effects.
          // Remove this when webpack adds a warning or an error for this.
          // See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6571
          sideEffects: true,
        }
```

Comment: If you are using `create-react-app` version `2+`, then you don't have to `eject`. it default come up with `css module` which you can use css classes directly inside your `js` file. but the trick is to create your `css` file  with `your_js_file_name.module.css` .then import it and use it. for more details see this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Le6GWQAMDg.

Answer (score 0):

(I have no enough reputation to add a comment to your question)

well, I wanted to enable CSS modules so I ended up doing this.
It took me a while to figure out in the new version.
after you have successfully ejected, just only edit **webpack.config.js** file and add the two lines of code  (check the code below)

```
....
....
{
          test: cssRegex,
          exclude: cssModuleRegex,
          use: getStyleLoaders({
            importLoaders: 1,

            modules: true, // add this line 
            localIdentName: "[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]", // add this line too

            sourceMap: isEnvProduction
              ? shouldUseSourceMap
              : isEnvDevelopment
          }),
....
....
```

[image: only edit webpack.config.js]

some more pics how to use CSS loaders:

my **Layout.css** file:

[image: my layout.css file]

my **Layout.js** file:

[image: my layout.js file]

Comment: `const cssRegex = /\.css$/;`  (it's declared in global variable)